# how to send money from ethereum wallet to another

Tags: infura

In a webserver with server-side javascipt language
I would like to insert a script to transfer money from my ethereum wallet managed by eidoo.io, to the address of other ethereum wallets. 
I'm documenting about infura and web3js, but I still do not understand if it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to export your private key. When I googled about edioo.io Ethereum wallet, they provide you a 12-word mnemonic that you can generate wallet. 
https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-wallet.html#creating-instances by following this documentation, you can recover your wallet which includes private key, public key and address of the account (via `ethers . Wallet . fromMnemonic`).

Then, you are able to send ether as it is told in  ***Transfer Ether*** Section : 
https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-wallet.html#id2

Lastly, to use Infura as web provider, it is also included in documentation. 
https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-providers.html#connecting-to-ethereum

Best Wishes,

Comment: following your instructions ... solved the problem immediately ... thanks for the excellent response